# Are there toilets on the Hogwarts express?

Tags: harry-potter

I know that the students have to change into robes before arriving at Hogwarts, but where do they do this? They usually seem to just get members of the opposite sex to leave the carriage, pull down the blinds, and then put on the robes.

So, are there toilets on the Hogwarts express?

Comment: "*Where exactly the Hogwarts Express came from has never been conclusively proven, although it is a fact that there are secret records at the Ministry of Magic detailing a mass operation involving one hundred and sixty-seven Memory Charms and the largest ever mass Concealment Charm performed in Britain. The morning after these alleged crimes, a gleaming scarlet steam engine and carriages astounded the villagers of Hogsmeade (who had also not realised they had a railway station)"*; https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express - Muggle trains invariably have toilets.

Comment: They usually get changed in the carriages.

Comment: @Valorum "*Muggle trains invariably have toilets*" - [citation needed]. I've been on many trains in Britain which don't have any toilets.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - What you are describing are local trains. Perhaps I should have said long-distance trains invariably have toilets.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: @MikasaPinata if the caslte, built in middle ages had plumbing, surely the train did.

Comment: @Skooba this just raises more questions. Modern trains use tanks to store the- ah, nevermind, MAGIC. I get it now.

Comment: @MikasaPinata - don't pay attention to naysayers. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I was under impression that calling posts "stupid' and other insulting terms is considered a violation of "be nice" policy? {{ ... [Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person. **That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny")**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) }}. Main site isn't Mos Eisley where being rude to people who aren't popular is just fine.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile In fairness to the user(s) who called the question "stupid", the OP was the first to call it "stupid". I've deleted all those comments, though -- the comment thread on this post was getting too long anyway and needed to be cleaned up a bit.

Comment: @Null - self deprecating humour is presumably exempt from "be nice" policy (not sure TBH). But IMHO it doesn't give anyone else the right to violate said policy. I'll ask on main Meta

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I agree that users should avoid using such terms even if the OP uses it first. I'm just noting that the use of the word "stupid" didn't come out of the blue in this case.

Comment: @Null - the worst part is that "not out of the blue" is actually the fact that it's *habitual* among some users to disparage other users' posts, especially questions, in rude terms.

Comment: @Null - fyi: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284489/does-repeating-non-nice-statements-made-by-the-target-itself-violate-be-nice-p, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284488/do-self-directed-not-nice-statements-violate-be-nice-policy

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yep, absolutely.

> The journey home on the Hogwarts Express next day was eventful in several ways. Firstly, Malfoy, Crabbe and Goyle, who had clearly been waiting all week for the opportunity to strike without teacher witnesses, attempted to ambush Harry halfway down the train **as he made his way back from the toilet.**
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.761 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 38, *The Second War Begins*

Comment: @Skooba I like railways so I liked your answer, but yeah, it was in the books :P

Comment: @Skooba Nope, don't have any ebooks, this is the old fashioned way - having read the books too many times and thumbing through my treasured hard backs for the exact bit :P Still, they're only four paces away :P

Comment: @Au101 +1 for a brilliant find. I've read the whole series (exept the cursed child) about 20 times from cover to cover and I still wasn't sure about this before I read your answer. So good job!!

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR - YES**; because Muggle trains from the same period would have had bathrooms, and the Hogwarts Express started as a Muggle one.

---

I preface this answer knowning full well the many in the SFF.SE community refer to the films as "nonsense", however off I go!

---

The train used in the films to portray the Hogwarts Express was the [*Olton Hall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GWR_4900_Class_5972_Olton_Hall#Hogwarts_Express),  no. 5972, 4-6-0 Hall class locomotive. This locomotive was built in 1937 (with the first Hall class being built in 1928). This would mean it was probably not the first engine to be used as the Express, but even with reading the [Hogwarts Express piece on Pottermore,](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express) it is hard pin down an exact in-service date for the train. I would assume that coaches are from the same period (but the newer the coaches are the even likelier chance of them having a bathroom).

As toilets would probably be considered a necessity on trains traveling inter-city, [bathrooms were installed](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100321155208AAMlRSV) on the passenger trains. Early trains used a [hopper toilet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_train_toilet), which would deposit the waste directly on the tracks.

Now the Hogwarts Express was a Muggle train (as we see in the above linked Pottermore article) and was modified before being put in magical service.

> The Hogwarts Express underwent several magical modifications before the Ministry approved it for school use. Many pure-blood families were outraged at the idea of their children using Muggle transport, which they claimed was unsafe, insanitary and demeaning; however, as the Ministry decreed that students either rode the train or did not attend school, the objections were swiftly silenced.

One would surely hope that one of the "magical modifications" was not to *remove* sanitary facilities!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. Some people are comfortable changing in their cabins, but others change in the bathrooms. It is a long journey, so there are toilets, definitely.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?

Comment: @Blackwood everyone poops?!

Comment: @Himarm I agree it's a reasonable assumption, but the answer includes more than that and reads as though it is meant to be authoritative.